Are separable subspaces totally bounded in an equivalent metric
By embedding a separable metric space into the Hilbert cube it is possible to show that every separable metric space is homeomorphic to a totally bounded metric space (see separable iff homeomorphic to totally bounded). Essentially the same procedure also gives there is an equiavlent metric which is totally bounded (this is more the approach given in Theorem 2.8.2. of Dudley's real analysis and probability book).
Is it possible to do a similar thing for only a separable subspace?
Specifically, let $X$ be a metrizable topological space and $S\subseteq X$ separable. Is there a metric on $d$ on $X$ (or an embedding of $X$ into a metric space) such that $S$ is totally bounded in $d$ (or its embedding is totally bounded)?

Yes, this is true. Recall first that any metric is equivalent to a metric bounded by $1$. Indeed, if $d$ is a metric, then $d’ = \min\{d, 1\}$ is such an equivalent metric, so we may choose a metric $d_X$ bounded by $1$ that generates the topology on $X$. By taking the closure of $S$, we may assume WLOG that $S$ is closed in $X$.
We now define our embedding as follows: Fix a countable dense subset $\{s_n\}_n$ of $S$. Let $Y = [0, 1]^{\mathbb{N} \sqcup X}$ be equipped with the following metric:
$$d_Y((r_i), (t_i)) = (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}|r_n - t_n|) + \sup_{x \in X} |r_x - t_x|$$
That is, the topology on $Y$ is pointwise convergence on coordinates labeled with natural numbers and uniform convergence on coordinates labeled with elements of $X$. Now, we define $\pi: X \to Y$,
$$[\pi(x)]_i = \begin{cases}
d_X(x, s_i)&, \text{ if }i \in \mathbb{N}\\
d_X(x, S \cup \{i\})&, \text{ if }i \in X
\end{cases}$$
I claim that $\pi$ is an embedding:
Continuity: For any set $A \subset X$, any $x, y \in X$, and $\epsilon > 0$, we note that there exists $a \in A$ s.t. $d_X(x, a) < d_X(x, A) + \epsilon$, so,
$$d_X(y, A) \leq d_X(y, a) \leq d_X(x, y) + d_X(x, a) < d_X(x, y) + d_X(x, A) + \epsilon$$
Letting $\epsilon \to 0$ shows $d_X(y, A) \leq d_X(x, y) + d_X(x, A)$. Similarly, $d_X(x, A) \leq d_X(x, y) + d_X(y, A)$, so $|d_X(y, A) - d_X(x, A)| \leq d_X(x, y)$. The RHS is independent of $A$, from which continuity of $\pi$ easily follows.
Injectivity and topological embedding: It suffices to show that, if $(x_n) \subset X$ and $x \in X$ are s.t. $\pi(x_n) \to \pi(x)$, then $x_n \to x$. We divide into two cases,

$x \notin S$: As $\pi(x_n) \to \pi(x)$, we have,

$$\begin{split}
\min\{d_X(x, S), d_X(x, x_n)\} &= d_X(x, S \cup \{x_n\})\\
&\leq d_X(x_n, S \cup \{x_n\}) + d_Y(\pi(x), \pi(x_n))\\
&= d_Y(\pi(x), \pi(x_n)) \to 0
\end{split}$$
As $S$ is closed and $x \notin S$, $d_X(x, S) \neq 0$, so $d_X(x, x_n) \to 0$, i.e., $x_n \to x$.

$x \in S$: Let $\epsilon > 0$. As $\{s_n\}_n$ is dense in $S$, we may fix $k$ s.t. $d_X(x, s_k) < \epsilon$. As $\pi(x_n) \to \pi(x)$, we in particular have $d_X(x_n, s_k) \to d_X(x, s_k)$. Thus, for large $n$, $d_X(x_n, s_k) < d_X(x, s_k) + \epsilon < 2\epsilon$. Hence, for large $n$,

$$d_X(x_n, x) \leq d_X(x_n, s_k) + d_X(x, s_k) < 3\epsilon$$
i.e., $d_X(x_n, x) \to 0$, so $x_n \to x$.
It now suffices to show that $\pi(S)$ is totally bounded, which follows easily by noting that, for $s \in S$, $\pi(s)$ has all its coordinates labeled by elements of $X$ being $0$, so $\pi(S) \subset [0, 1]^\mathbb{N} \times \{0\}^X$, and the latter is simply the Hilbert cube under $d_Y$.
